# VBA copy pastespecial method of range class failed 1004

Tags: excel, vba

Re-editing the post due to a new issue. This time, I passed the issue on creating a new workbook, but now, the past special value do not work properly. 
I need to copy paste 8 times the same sheets into a new one, with each refreshed by a different Geographies (i.e. Europe, North America etc..).
I get each time a - Run time error '1004' as specified in the title. I'd like to paste as value, formats and column widths as the initial sheet has formulas. How can I update the vba to make it work? :-) Thank you in advance Team.

```
Sub Export()
Dim lRow, lCol As Integer
Workbooks.Add
Path = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("Desktop") & "\"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Path & "GMCommits.xlsm",    FileFormat:=XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
Workbooks("1").Activate
Sheets("1").Select
Range("E4").Value = "8" 
Application.Calculate

Sheets("2").Select
lRow = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

For Each cell In Range(Cells(1, "C"), Cells(1, lCol))
Union(Range("C1:AE" & lRow), Range(Cells(1, cell.Column), Cells(lRow, cell.Column))).Copy

Workbooks("2").Activate
Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths
Next cell
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

The code is stopping at the second Range A1 pastespecial. 
The VBA routine is to refresh 8 times the value from the Geographies, and copy paste it into a new sheets in the workbook 2 then finish the module by End sub.

Comment: The problem seems pretty clear - you can't save a workbook using the same name as an already-open workbook (and you never close any of the workbooks you've created in the loop).  Are you really using the same name each time?

Comment: @TimWilliams yes I do have 7 names to be refreshed and copy pasted into the new workbook. It is the reason you see the change value = 8 in the code. So each time looping to the same condition, refresh cell value to 7,6,5,4... and for each of them create a new worksheet with different name into the same workbook, which is then saved locally.

Comment: `Workbooks.Add` creates a new workbook, not a new worksheet.

Comment: @TimWilliams would that allow to have the 8 worksheets all into the same workbook? or should I move then the save as path at the end of the code?

Comment: @TimWilliams thanks Tim. I was able to correct the error thanks to your guidance, now I face a new error from the code for the paste special view. Anyway appreciated the help greatly.